# Remove child class fields to be conform to parent class only

Tags: typescript

```
// Defined in a third party lib
interface A { x: string, ... hell a lot of other properties }
interface B extends A { y: string }

// Defined in our code, correct in most cases
const b: B = { x: "foo", y: "bar" }

// Separated case where I need to reuse 'b' as an A while having an y defined is a problem
// How do I convert 'b' to A by removing b-property without creating a copy?
delete b.y; // Fails because a B variable must have y (y is not optional)
delete (b as A).y; // Fails because A does not have a b
```

Comment: the property y needs to be nullable with like `y?: string` otherwise you need to copy the object and exclude the key `y`

Comment: If you're wiling to use type assertions then just `delete (b as Partial<B>).y;` or `delete (b as any).y` will work, but why would you want to do that?  After that line, the compiler will mistakenly believe that `b` still has a `y` property.  What's wrong with just copying like `const { y, ...a } = b;`?